# Incremento de 0.30% de un número al propio número de forma semanal

Tags: javascript

Necesito el código JS para añadir a una página web:

1. Tengo una #cantidad (id) y necesito aumentarla el 0,03 %
   (incremento) de esa misma automáticamente cada 7 días (tiempo).
2. Este número resultante debe ser una cifra redonda; sin decimales.
3. Finalmente sustituir esa cantidad en la web document (id: #cantidad)

Muchas gracias.

Lo que intente hacer fue algo así:

```
<h1 id="cantidad">100 cantidad</h1>


<script>


const incremento = 0.03; // % a incrementar 0.03
var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").innerHTML; // Get id="cantidad"
var cantidadIncremento = cantidad + incremento; // id + incremento


document.getElementById("cantidad").innerHTML = cantidadIncremento;


</script>
```

Comment: VICODE, recuerda que en la comunidad apoyamos a que logres el objetivo, no lo desarrollamos nosotros. Debes incluir lo que llevas, hacer un ejemplo mínimo verificable.

Comment: Edita tu publicación y agregalo, no como comentario

Comment: Gracias Alberto.

Comment: Algo que no entiendo es cada 7 dias deberia refrescar el valor?

Comment: Sí, cada tiempo X (Cada lunes o cada 7 días) aumentar un 0.03 % el valor inicial.

Si la cantidad es 100
La primera semana será 100
La segunda sera 103, 106, 109, así sucesivamente.

Comment: Necesitas una forma de persistir esos datos, el incremento (0.03%) que planteas (103, 106, 109) es siempre sobre el valor inicial, por lo visto. Son muchas cosas que creo que no has tomado en cuenta. ¿Podrías aclarar un poco más lo que deseas hacer? Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si bien el ideal es guardar la cantidad de semanas transcurridas y la cantidad, este problema se puede resolver teóricamente conociendo solo la fecha inicial, porque el incremento de 0.03 por cada semana se puede expresar como una progresión geométrica de la forma: cantidad_Inicial X incremento<sup>semanas</sup>

```js
//Fecha inicial para hacer los cálculos ejemplo 2 de diciembre
const fechaBase = new Date('12/02/2019').getTime();
const hoy = new Date().getTime();

//diferencia en milisegundos
const diferencia = hoy - fechaBase;

// /1000 son los segundos
// /60 son los minutos
// /60 son las horas
// /24 son los días
// /7 nos dara la cantidad de grupos de 7 dias que hay en ese númeno

const semanasTranscurridas = diferencia/1000/60/60/24/7;
const cantidadInicial = 100;

//Progresión geométrica
const cantidadTotal = cantidadInicial*(1.03**Math.floor(semanasTranscurridas));

document.getElementById("cantidad").innerText = Math.floor(cantidadTotal);
```

```html
<h1 id="cantidad"></h1>
```

El `Math.floor` de semanas es para considerar semanas completas, y el `Math.floor` de la última cantidad es arbitrario, podría ser `ceil` también, dependerá de como quieras redondear.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he intentado incorporarlo pero no lo consigo.

¿Como podría hacer una función con esto y que me haga return de el número a sustituir?

Comment: Podrías hacer algo asi: https://jsfiddle.net/ux0wbsyk/

Comment: Muchas gracias Emeeus, sigo intentándolo aunque no lo consigo.

Me ha surgido la duda, como puedo recuperar el 'id del numero ' de 'clientes' y 'facturas' de la parte baja de esta página: https://bit.ly/3625Fwt e incluirlo en la Id del Script.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

A ver, de alguna forma ya sea por PHP o algun otro lenguaje de backend el valor inicial de cantidad deberá venir forzosamente por una base de datos, de lo contrario tu código va a empezar a ser un caos

Ahora, saqué la cantidad del `h1` por que tiene añadido el 'cantidad' y eso provocaría errores al momento de hacer los cálculos, lo puse en un `span` así se puede hacer lo que se necesita y no pierde el estilo.

Hoy no es lunes, así que para que funcionara en la variable `es_lunes` en la comparación cambia de o a 1

Te dejo un ejemplo para que te orientes.

```js
// Esta es tu variable de aumento
const aumento  = 0.03;

// Este es un booleano basado en el día de la semana que es hoy, en este caso sigue siendo domingo, si requieres el lunes cambia a 1
const es_lunes = new Date().getDay() === 0;

// Obten el valor de #cantidad y castea a numero
const cantidad = Number(document.getElementById('cantidad').innerHTML);

// Si es lunes entonces se actualizará el dato
if( es_lunes ) {
  const nueva_cantidad = Math.round( (cantidad * aumento) + cantidad);
  document.getElementById('cantidad').innerHTML = nueva_cantidad;
}
```

```html
<h1> <span id="cantidad">1000</span> cantidad</h1>
```